# I am working on GAM models and I am having an error with rgl to work in RStudio, I have downloaded X11 on my Machine

Tags: rgl

My system environment:

Mac OS: Mac Mojave (10.14.6)
X11 (XQuartz 2.7.11)
R (3.6.3)

What should I do to get rgl package to work with mgcViz work on my machine. On xterm if I type install.packages("rgl") I get an error syntax error near unexpected token 'rgl'. I am having trouble getting the steps to work. Spent hours together and I am out of luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update to the latest version of R which was compatible to rgl which required R 4.0.0 or higher. I did install rgl with dependecies. I was able to get the desired output.